# Regex matching only a portion of string

Tags: regex

I would like to match a portion of a URL in this order.

First the domain name will remain static. So, nothing check with regex.

```
$domain_name = "http://foo.com/";
```

What I would like to validate is what comes after the last `/`.

So, my AIM is to create something like.

```
$stings_only            = "[\w+]";
$number_only            = "[\d+]";
$numbers_and_strings    = "[0-9][a-z][A-Z]";
```

Now, I would like to just use the above variables to check if a URL confirms to the patterns mentioned.

```
$example_url = "http://foo.com/some-title-with-id-1"; 

var_dump(preg_match({$domain_name}{$strings_only}, $example_url));
```

The above should return false, because title is NOT $string_only.

```
$example_url = "http://foo.com/foobartar"; 

var_dump(preg_match({$domain_name}{$strings_only}, $example_url));
```

The above should return true, because title is $string_only.

Comment: 1. You really need to read about using regex 2. You don't need regex for this problem.

Comment: @anubhava You don't understand. The `/./` is just an example. It could also be `\d+` or any other pattern. So, regex is needed

Comment: [*regex is needed*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) is a very bold statement.

Comment: Nice read. Thanks for the share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

```
~^http://foo\.com/[a-z]+/?$~i
~^http://foo\.com/[0-9]+/?$~
~^http://foo\.com/[a-z0-9]+/?$~i
```

These would be your three expressions to match alphabetical URLs, numeric URLS, and alphanumeric.  A couple notes, `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so I don't think it is what you expected.  The `+` inside of your character class (`[]`) does not have any special meaning, like you may expect.  `\w` and `\d` are "shorthand character classes" and do not need to be within the `[]` syntax (however they can be, e.g. `[\w.,]`).  Notice the `i` modifier, this makes the expressions case-insensitive so we do not need to use `[a-zA-Z]`.

```
$strings_only = '~^http://foo\.com/[a-z]+/?$~i';

$url = 'http://foo.com/some-title-with-id-1';
var_dump(preg_match($strings_only, $url)); // int(0)

$url = 'http://foo.com/foobartar';
var_dump(preg_match($strings_only, $url)); // int(1)
```

Test/tweak all of my above expressions with [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/hE8cQ0).

---

`.` matches any character, but only once.  Use `.*` for 0+ or `.+` for 1+.  However, these will be greedy and match your whole string and can potentially cause problems.  You can make it lazy by adding `?` to the end of them (meaning it will stop as soon as it sees the next character `/`).  Or, you can specify anything ***but*** a `/` using a negative character class `[^/]`.

My [final regex of choice](http://regex101.com/r/aN1wK7) would be:

```
~^https://stolak\.ru/([^/]+)/?$~
```

Notice the `~` delimiters, so that you don't need to escape every `/`.  Also, you need to escape the `.` with `\` since it has a special meaning.  I threw the `[^/]+` URI parameter into a capture group and made the trailing slash optional by using `/?`.  Finally, I anchored this to the beginning and the end of the strings (`^` and `$`, respectively).

Your question was somewhat vague, so I tried to interpret what you wanted to match.  If I was wrong, let me know and I can update it.  However, I tried to explain it all so that you could learn and tweak it to your needs.  Also, play with my [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aN1wK7) link -- it will make testing easier.

---

**Implementation:**

```
$pattern = '~^https://stolak\.ru/([^/]+)/?$~';
$url = 'https://stolak.ru/car-type-b1';

preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(29) "https://stolak.ru/car-type-b1"
//   [1]=>
//   string(11) "car-type-b1"
// }
```

Comment: getting error `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '~' found`

Comment: You copied the expression wrong, make sure you have the `~` on both sides...see my PHP code in the edit.

Comment: Still this did not answer the problem. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Did you even read through my answer? Or just try to plug it in.. RE: *`"Your question was somewhat vague, so I tried to interpret what you wanted to match. If I was wrong, let me know and I can update it."`* -- update your question and I can help, no one else will be able to do anything better than a guess.